# How to use formula in power query - excel

Tags: excel, powerquery

I used formula `=IF($A1<>$A2,COUNTIF(A:A,$A2),"")` in excel column '**J2**'. There are **n** rows in sheet. I want to apply this formula to all rows. In excel we do copy formula by drag and drop.

How can I achieve the same using power query.

currently I'm using power query to load external data in excel.

Any input will be helpful.. Thanks

Comment: That looks like counting unique instances of items in columnA,  In powerquery, right click Column A, choose Group By ,,,, and use operation Count Rows

Comment: @horseyride, Yes, it is counting rows. The rows(column A values) are in ascending order. The first row should only show count value. The following matching rows should be empty. I tried GroupBy and Count in power query but it show count in all matching rows...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming data is **Table1** with first column sorted and named **Column1**

Group and for the two operations, use **Count Rows** and **All Rows**

Expand

Add Index

Use index to refer to prior row

If current row's Column1 = prior row's Column1 then null otherwise the count

Remove extra columns

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"Column1"}, {{"Count", each Table.RowCount(_), type number}, {"Data", each _, type table}}),
#"Expanded Data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Data", {"Column1"}, {"Column1.1"}),
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Expanded Data", "Index", 0, 1),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Custom", each if [Index]=0 then [Count] else if #"Added Index"{[Index]} [Column1] = #"Added Index"{[Index]-1} [Column1] then null else [Count]),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Column1.1", "Index"})
in #"Removed Columns"
```